Axios interceptor cause loop on navigating
I use axios interceptor to check if a user is logged in or not when processing a request. If not, I will redirect them to login page. The problem is when user being redirected to login page, they must click back about 3-4 times before they can go back to the previous page. I don't know why this happens although only one request is sent on every action.
Here is my interceptor:
const usePrivateAxios = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const location = useLocation();

  const currentPath = location.pathname;

  useEffect(() => {
    const requestInterceptor = privateAxios.interceptors.request.use(
      (config) => {
        const accessToken = localStorage.getItem("accessToken");
        const user = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("profile"));

        if (!accessToken || !user) {
          if (currentPath.includes("/admin")) {
            navigate("/admin/login");
          } else if (currentPath.includes("/manager")) {
            navigate("/manager/login");
          } else {
            navigate("/login");
          }

          toast.error(
            <p className="pr-2">Vui lòng đăng nhập trước!</p>,
            toastOptions,
          );
        } else {
          config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${accessToken}`;
          sessionStorage.removeItem("entryMessage");
        }
        return config;
      },
      (error) => Promise.reject(error),
    );

    const responseInterceptor = privateAxios.interceptors.response.use(
      (response) => {
        const user = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("profile"));

        if (response.data.status === 401 || response.data.status === 403) {
          if (response.data.status === 401) {
            toast.error(
              <p className="pr-2">Vui lòng đăng nhập trước!</p>,
              toastOptions,
            );
          } else if (response.data.status === 403) {
            toast.error(
              <p className="pr-2">Tài khoản không có quyền truy cập!</p>,
              toastOptions,
            );
          }

          if (user && user.role && user.role.roleName === "ROLE_ADMIN") {
            navigate("/admin/login");
          } else if (
            user &&
            user.role &&
            user.role.roleName === "ROLE_MANAGER"
          ) {
            navigate("/manager/login");
          } else {
            navigate("/login");
          }
        }
        return response;
      },
      (error) => {
        return Promise.reject(error);
      },
    );

    return () => {
      privateAxios.interceptors.request.eject(requestInterceptor);
      privateAxios.interceptors.response.eject(responseInterceptor);
    };
  }, [navigate]);
  return privateAxios;
};

Updated:
For example, I use it to handle request for like a post:
// API
export const likePost = async (postId, config) => {
    try {
        const response = await privateAxios.post(`/posts/${postId}/like`, config);
        return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
        throw error;
    }
};

// Func
const handlePostLike = async () => {
    if (post && post.my) {
        toast.error(<p className="pr-2">Bạn không thể thích/bỏ thích bài đăng của mình!</p>, toastOptions);
    } else {
        try {
            const response = await likePost(postId);
            if (response.status === 200) {
                getPostDetail();
            }
        catch (error) {
            navigate("/error-500");
        }
    }
};


can you show the code that you using this interceptor

@DileepaMabulage I've updated some code in the question
